# opencv 4.5.4 with StreamCam Plus not getting expected FPS

Tags: opencv, webcam, frame-rate, mjpeg, logitech

I am using a MSI GS66 Stealth with a logitech StreamCam Plus and openCV_4.5.4. The code is below. For some reason I am only able to get a max of ~30 fps despite setting the fps to 60. It should be noted that I can slow the fps to say 5 fps as shown in Figure 2 below...

According to logitech the streamCam Plus supports 60fps while in MJPEG mode, see Figure 2... I believe I have set this properly in the code via a call to:

```
...
int fourcc = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc);
...
```

Additionally, I have tried to change the cameras settings in both the Logitech Capture and Logi Tune software. Currently, the camera is set to completely manual via the Logi tune software

[image]

Figure 1: supports 60fps while in MJPEG format

[image]

Figure 2: has 5 fps and loops at 5 fps

[image]

Figure 3: has 60 fps however it loops at ~30fps

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>//OpenCV header to use VideoCapture class//
#include<iostream>

using timer = std::chrono::system_clock;
timer::time_point clock_cur;
timer::time_point clock_last;

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    using fmilliseconds = chrono::duration<float, std::milli>;
    //Mat myImage(240, 320, CV_8UC1);//Declaring a matrix to load the frames//
    Mat myImage;
    namedWindow("Video Player");//Declaring the video to show the video//
    VideoCapture cap(1,CAP_DSHOW+0);//Declaring an object to capture stream of frames from default camera//
    if (!cap.isOpened()) { //This section prompt an error message if no video stream is found//
        cout << "No video stream detected" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return-1;
    }

    //setUseOptimized(true);

    float avgDur = 0;
    bool useShortWindow = true;
    int maxWindowSize = 10;
    int curWindowSize = 0;
    int loopCnt = curWindowSize;

    bool bVal = true;
    int fourcc = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc);

    int val = 0;
    int val2 = 0;

    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);

    //cap.set(CAP_PROP_ZOOM, 125);
    //cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOCUS, 10);
    bVal = cap.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 60);
    
    //cap.set(CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 2);


    clock_cur = timer::now();
    clock_last = clock_cur;

    while (true) { //Taking an everlasting loop to show the video//

        clock_cur = timer::now();

        cap >> myImage;
        //Mat imgBlur;
        //GaussianBlur(myImage, imgBlur, Size(7, 7), 0);
        //GaussianBlur(myImage, myImage, Size(7, 7), 0);
        //cvtColor(myImage, myImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        //cvtColor(imgBlur, imgBlur, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        
        //Mat image = myImage;
        //for (int y = 0; y < myImage.rows; y++)
        //{
        //    for (int x = 0; x < myImage.cols; x++)
        //    {
        //        //Get pixel value
        //        int pixelValue = (int)myImage.at<uchar>(y, x);
        //
        //        if (pixelValue < 60)
        //            pixelValue = 0;
        //        else if (pixelValue > 175)
        //            pixelValue = 255;
        //        else
        //            pixelValue = 128;
        //
        //        myImage.at<uchar>(y,x) = pixelValue;
        //
        //    }
        //}

        //if (myImage.empty()) { //Breaking the loop if no video frame is detected//
            //break;
        //}

        imshow("No Blur", myImage);//Showing the video//
        //imshow("Video Player", imgBlur);//Showing the video//

            fmilliseconds Duration = clock_cur - clock_last;

            val = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
            val2 = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

            if (useShortWindow && loopCnt < maxWindowSize)
                curWindowSize = loopCnt;
            else
            {
                useShortWindow = false;
                curWindowSize = maxWindowSize;
            }

        if (curWindowSize > 1)
        {
            avgDur = avgDur / curWindowSize * (curWindowSize - 1) + Duration.count() / 1000 / curWindowSize;
            cout << to_string(val) << " : " << to_string(val2) << " : " << to_string(1 / avgDur) << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            avgDur = Duration.count() / 1000;
            cout << to_string(val) << " : " << to_string(val2) << " : " << to_string(1 / Duration.count()) << "\n";
        }
            
        char c = (char)waitKey(1);//Allowing 25 milliseconds frame processing time and initiating break condition//
        //if (c == 27) { //If 'Esc' is entered break the loop//
        //    break;
        //}
        clock_last = clock_cur;
        loopCnt = useShortWindow ? loopCnt + 1 : maxWindowSize;
    }

    cap.release();//Releasing the buffer memory//
    return 0;
}
```

Figure 4: Code has been trimmed to just print size and fps.

Certainly, I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also asked on https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-4-5-4-with-streamcam-plus-not-getting-expected-fps/16717